# quaternion To Euler algorithm. getPitch() returns Nan?

Tags: c#, nan, euler-angles

I am trying to convert the quaternion that I obtained from the sensor and get the pitch by calculating theta. If anyone is interested, have a look [in this article](https://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQFjAA&url=http://sharenet-wii-motion-trac.googlecode.com/files/An_efficient_orientation_filter_for_inertial_and_inertialmagnetic_sensor_arrays.pdf&ei=GpX_UZWABo2jiQf_mICIAQ&usg=AFQjCNEBfCip2CAVZhCKjxP1HYvVvWruYw&bvm=bv.50165853,d.aGc)- chapter 2

My problem is in the following code:

```
 private void quaternionToEuler(float[] q, float[] euler)
    {
        euler[0] = (float)Math.Atan2((2 * q[1] * q[2]) - (2 * q[0] * q[3]), (2 * q[0] * q[0]) + ((2 * q[1] * q[1]) - 1));
        euler[1] = -(float)Math.Asin(((2 * q[1] * q[3]) + (2 * q[0] * q[2]))); // theta
        euler[2] = (float)Math.Atan2((2 * q[2] * q[3]) - (2 * q[0] * q[1]), (2 * q[0] * q[0]) + ((2 * q[3] * q[3]) - 1)); // phi

        Console.WriteLine(euler[0] + ","+euler[1]+"," + euler[2]);
    }
```

**euler 1 which gets the pitch always returning Nan (not a number)**
I am not sure if I implemented the algorithm correctly. For some reason, Asin(d), where d the output is >1 and <-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that your quaternion is not normalised. Only normalised quaternions represent rotations in 3D, you must have that

```
q[0]*q[0] + q[1]*q[1] + q[2]*q[2] + q[3]*q[3] == 1
```

If this is the case, then we always have

```
d = q[1]*q[3] + q[0]*q[2] <= 0.5
```

as we have that

```
q[1]*q[3] <= 0.25 *(q[1] + q[3])^2
```

where `^` denotes power, by the [AM-GM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means), and similarly for `q[0]*q[2]`

now we have that

```
d <= 0.25 * ( (q[1] + q[3])^2 + (q[0] + q[2])^2 ) 
  <= 0.25 * ( q[1]^2 + q[2]^2 + q[3]^2 + q[4]^2 )
  <= 0.25
```

by the normality assumption.